# How can I provide permission to myself to push to github from the command line?

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, git-push

I am trying for the first time to use git and GitHub to version control my project.

Here is what i have done

1. I added a new SSH Key to my machine using the docs "[Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/)"
2. I created a project on GitHub without readme.md file as recommended.
3. Using the command line, I changed directory to my project. Then, I executed the commands listed below

However, the `git push` command is giving me the following error

> remote: Permission to VENDORNAME/PROJECT-NAME.git denied to
>   malhayek2014. fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/VENDORNAME/PROJECT-NAME.git/': The requested URL
>   returned error: 403

Here are the commands I ecexuted before running into the errors

```
echo "A message for the read me file" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/VENDOR-NAME/PROJECT-NAME.git
git push -u origin master
```

How can I communicate with Github and push code to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to use SSH for pushing and pulling you have to use the ssh URL (which looks like `git@github.com:username/project.git`) and not the https URL.

In order to update an existing repository you can issue the following command:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:VENDOR-NAME/PROJECT-NAME.git
```

See https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/

PS: The error message you provide indicates that you are successfully authenticated using https, however, you don't have persissions to push to that repository - that's independent to the SSH problem. You need to add yourself to the team if you are one of the owners or ask the owners to do so - or add your SSH key as a deployment key.

Comment: i see. Thank you for that. Do I have to provided that info each time I push code? can't that be saved some where where I just do `git push` ?

Comment: No, when you execute the command I specified it's saved in `.git/config`. You can also initially use `git remote add origin git@github.com:VENDOR-NAME/PROJECT-NAME.git` instead the command you used.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you can install github cli then everything will work

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31898772)